# Assist me to obtain an equation please?

Tags: functional-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have a plot which contain large number of points. I want to find an equation that calculates the percentage of a certain number of these points $(x,y)$, the ones having $x>5$ and $y>80$.

In other words, 100 $\times$ (all points higher than (5 in x-axis and 80 in y-axis)) / (all points in the plot).

How can I find this equation? Thank you!

Comment: Does this mean you have been given the data only as a graph/plot, or that you have a spreadsheet you are using?  If it is a graph/plot, consider drawing lines at $x=5$ and $y=80$.  If in a spreadsheet or CSV format, you may be able to use programming to filter first for $x\gt 5$ and then for $y\gt 80$.

Comment: No, I just want to write the equation in my report. But I want it in scientific math way. the question is how can I mathematically write an equation

Comment: Without the data you are using, there is not really any "formula" or equation to determine the proportion which have these characteristics. As @abiessu noted above, if you have the data in a spreadsheet and can test which number of datapoints satisfy $x>5$, $y>80$, then it would just be this number of datapoints divided by your total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially there.  Often we put vertical bars around a set to indicate the number of elements, so if your set of points is set $A$ you could write $\frac {|\{(x,y)|(x,y) \in A \land x \gt 5 \land y \gt 80\}|}{|A|}$ where the numerator is in [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).  The vertical bar says "take all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy all this".  By the way, this is an expression, not an equation, as it isn't shown as equal to anything.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. I understood the expression. but why do we have (x,y)|(x,y) two times ? and what does ∧ means ?

Comment: $\land$ means and.  The first $(x,y)$ says our set consists of ordered pairs.  The second one is tied to $\in A$ so they must be part of your data set.

Comment: ok, its clear now. many thanks again :)